# SSD upgrade with adapter for HP ProBook 450 G3

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, adapter

Since I am not quite familiar with the insides of laptops I do need some help and so far my own research is far from conclusive.

I have a SSD drive:
Intel Solid-State Drive 660p Series - Solid state drive - encrypted - 2 TB - internal - M.2 2280 - PCI Express 3.0 x4 (NVMe) - 256-bit AES
from [here](https://www.markit.eu/lv/en/intel-solid-state-drive-660p-series-solid-state/v2p16778682c140104) and I have a laptop:
HP ProBook 450 G3 P4P50EA#AKD.

The laptop has 256GB SSD installed from factory and that is full. It also has a space for another drive right next to RAM as shown here on the left right below the monkey as seen [here](https://www.google.lv/search?q=HP+Probook+450+G3+P4P50+ssd&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=QWhEHbIMVj7gRM%253A%252CkWGEoOurMLPP2M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSzKTaeiiFC2si03pbEeoeyEoHLPw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjipLaU6d7iAhWvw6YKHbJ0AksQ9QEwC3oECAQQBA#imgrc=QWhEHbIMVj7gRM:)

So my question is - is there an adapter or something so that I can connect the bought SSD to this slot? I was confident that this SSD could replace the factory-installed one but it turned out - it doesn't fit, so I hope there is an adapter for that.

Comment: A PCIe SSD cannot work with a SATA connector. But your notebook apparently has a slot for this SSD elsewhere. There should be another maintenance hatch. Check there.

Comment: The other slot is currently used by the factory-installed SSD drive. The difference between the original and the new SSD, from my perspective, is that the original SSD has 2 gaps in the connector while the new SSD has only 1 gap so it does not fit, if you know what I mean by that. At least it does not go there voluntarily, maybe with force but that does not seem like a good idea to force it in.
So, in essence, this new SSD does not fit anywhere on my laptop...

Comment: I am guessing with gaps ypu mean the M2 notches. (See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/M2_Edge_Connector_Keying.svg/400px-M2_Edge_Connector_Keying.svg.png)  IT prevents things like proper M2 NVME drive being put in a M@ connector which only supports SATA and not NVME.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by gaps.

So, let me get this straight. I cannot put the SSD in the original SSD slot because the connectors do not match. And I cannot also put the SSD with an adapter in the spare space because there is no connector like that. Is that correct?

Comment: The M.2 *slot* should only have a single notch though. Are you sure it has two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the photos in [this review](https://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-ProBook-450-G3-Notebook-Review.155716.0.html) of your notebook, I come to the conclusion that your notebook has a “B-keyed” M.2 slot. Unfortunately, the SSD you bought is “M-keyed”. It cannot fit in this slot. You’ll have to return it.

Additionally, your notebook also supports an additional 2.5″ SATA drive. If your notebook does not include the necessary mounting kit, you need to purchase it separately. Or just stuff the empty spaces with paper or whatever so the drive does not disconnect accidentally.

Purchasing a SATA SSD is easier (all are compatible) if you don’t need the performance a PCIe SSD can offer.

The page you linked to (markit.eu) unfortunately does not offer the required filters. Instead, you can research [here](https://geizhals.eu/?cat=hdssd&xf=4832_3%7E9903_2) (the required filters are already selected) and then buy from a local dealer.

Comment: Clear! Thank you so very much for the help. Now, I think, I will get the right one! Thank you!